# How can I write a const propagating pointer type wrapper?

Tags: c++, c++17

To better understand the C++ type system, I have endeavored to write a pointer wrapper class which propagates constness similar to std::experimental::propagate_const:

```
template <typename Pointee> class Ptr {
public:
  Ptr() = delete;

  explicit Ptr(Pointee *);

  Ptr(const Ptr<Pointee> &) = delete;
  Ptr(Ptr<Pointee> &&);

  Ptr<Pointee> &operator=(const Ptr<Pointee> &) = delete;
  Ptr<Pointee> &operator=(Ptr<Pointee> &&);

  ~Ptr()  = default;

  const Pointee *operator->() const;
  Pointee *operator->();
  const Pointee &operator*() const;
  Pointee &operator*();

private:
  Pointee *mPtr;
};
```

The wrapper is intended to provide near raw pointer like behavior while also enforcing a kind of 'deep' const correctness and guarding against unintentional aliasing.

To this end, the copy constructor and copy assignment operator are deleted:

1. To prevent unintentional aliasing of the pointed-to object by
   copying from a Ptr.
2. To prevent non-const access of a const
   pointed-to object by copying a const Ptr into a non-const Ptr.

However, the above design has two unfortunate consequences.

1. A const Ptr cannot be moved into a either a const or non-const Ptr. When C++17's mandatory RVO does not apply, this means that a const Ptr object cannot be returned from a function.
2. Due to C++17's mandatory copy/move-elision, in certain situations a non-const Ptr can be constructed from a const Ptr even though no such viable constructor exists. For instance, the code below will compile just fine (ignore the memory leak/raw new for the purpose of demonstration):

```
const Ptr<int> allocateImmutableInt(int val) { return Ptr<int>(new int(val)); }


void foo() {
  Ptr<int> immutableInt = allocateImmutableInt(0); // Initializes non-const Ptr from const Ptr 
  *immutableInt = 100;  // Oops, changed value of 'immutable' object
}
```

The first problem can be partially solved by introducing a move ctor that accepts a const rvalue reference (although this feels somewhat strange and non-idiomatic):

```
  Ptr(const Ptr<Pointee> &&);
```

However, this actually worsens the second problem. Now a const Ptr can be move constructed into a non-const Ptr even without mandatory move/copy-elision. As far as I can tell, to get around this issue we would need a so called 'const constructor', ie a constructor which can only be invoked to produce a const object:

```
  Ptr(const Ptr<Pointee>&&) const;
```

Even if c++ supported such a constructor, the second problem would still remain, as c++17 specifically ignores cv-qualification and the viability of constructors when deciding if mandatory move/copy-elision can be applied when initializing an object. There does not currently appear to be a way to ask c++ to check if a copy/move would be viable before applying mandatory copy/move elision to object initialization.

As far as I can tell, std::experimental::propagate_const suffers from these same issues. I am wondering if I have encountered a fundamental limitation of c++, or if I am designing the Ptr wrapper incorrectly? I am aware that these issues can likely be eliminated by creating two types, a Ptr for non-const access and ConstPtr for const-only access. However, this defeats the purpose of creating a const-propagating wrapper in the first place.

Perhaps I have just stumbled upon the reason why both an iterator type and a const_iterator type exist.

Comment: You say that "the code below will compile just fine" but I don't believe it does. See https://godbolt.org/z/fa4EPn

Comment: Indeed it will not compile with c++14 or below. But if we add -std=c++17 as an argument in godbolt it does compile successfully due to guaranteed copy/move elision.

Comment: I assume `allocateImmutableInt` should point to an immutable data, so `Ptr<const int>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at problems that do not really exist.

> 2. To prevent non-const access of a const
>    pointed-to object by copying a const Ptr into a non-const Ptr.

This should not be a goal, as it goes against the idea of propagating `const`.

There are two aspects to propagating `const`. First, when the pointer is `const`-qualified, the object is also `const`-qualified. This aspect you have covered. Second, when the pointer is *not* `const`-qualified, the object uses its natural qualification. That is, if you can copy a `const Ptr` into a non-`const` `Ptr`, then that change propagates to the object, potentially making the object also non-`const`. This is desired propagation, not something to prevent.

Keep in mind a major use case for `const` propagation: class members. Propagating `const` for a member pointer helps ensure const-correctness by making the pointed-to data `const` in `const`-qualified member functions. Your imagined problems are not applicable to this use case. Don't make the situation more complex than it needs to be.

> I am aware that these issues can likely be eliminated by creating two types, a Ptr for non-const access and ConstPtr for const-only access.

This is not necessary. If the object is supposed to remain `const` even when the pointer is not `const`, then the type should be `Ptr<const T>` instead of `Ptr<T>`.
As an example, your "immutable int" should look more like the following.

```
Ptr<const int> allocateImmutableInt(int val) { return Ptr<const int>(new int(val)); }
    ^^^^^                                                 ^^^^^
```

The `const` has been moved to qualify the `int`, making the `int` immutable regardless of the `const`-qualification of the `Ptr`.

Furthermore, you might note that `new int(val)` returns an `int*` that gets implicitly converted to `const int*` for your constructor.  You might want to replicate this implicit conversion for `Ptr`. A constructor like `Ptr(Ptr<std::remove_const<Pointee>> &&)` would do the trick, as long as it is defined only when `Pointee` is `const`-qualified (to avoid having a conflict with the regular move constructor).

Answer (score 1):

```
Ptr<int> const allocateImmutableInt(int val) {
    return Ptr<int>(new int(val));
}
```

Doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't create a const-qualified object that is then passed to the constructor of `immutableInt`. -That would not even be possible as you deleted the copy constructor.-
Instead the compiler will infer

```
Ptr<int> immutableInt = allocateImmutableInt(0);
```

as

```
Ptr<int> immutableInt(new int(val));
```

If you write your main function as:

```
void foo() {
    Ptr<int> const immutableInt = allocateImmutableInt(0);
    Ptr<int> mutableInt = std::move(immutableInt);  // doesn't compile
    *mutableInt = 100;
}
```

You'll see correct behavior: the `move` is not possible due to const and the copy constructor is deleted.

edit:
By the way, your `Ptr` class looks a lot like `std::unique_ptr`. Thus you could just write:

```
#include <memory>
void foo() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> const immutableInt = std::make_unique<int>(0);
    std::unique_ptr<int> mutableInt = std::move(immutableInt);  // doesn't compile
    *mutableInt = 100;
}
```

And if you want a const-qualified pointer, write

```
std::unique_ptr<int const>
```